# Modify struct from function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to modify file in the items struct from parse_commandline().

I can without problems modify items->file from main() by using strncpy, but not from parse_commandline(). I need to modify parse_commandline() so it can recieve information about items from main(), by i don't know how?

```
typedef struct {
    int pack_01;
    int pack_02;
    char file[100];
} items;

static items character_y = { 1, 1 }

parse_commandline(int argc, char *argv[])
{

/* PARSE COMMANDLINE ARGUMENTS */

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    items *ptr_items = &character_y;

    parse_commandline(argc,argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass an additional param to parse_commandline, e.g. `parse_commandline(int argc, char *argv[], items *ptr_items)` ?

Comment: Because this do not seem to work -  warning: passing argument 3 of ‘parse_commandline’ from incompatible pointer type
note: expected ‘struct items *’ but argument is of type ‘struct items **’

Comment: `items` is a data type, you can only modify an instance, but you have not specified which instance.  In your example code the only instance of `items` is `character_y` which is visible in both `main()` and `parse_commandline()`, so  apart from being probably a bad design, it does not explain why you cannot access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is pass a pointer to `item`s to the `parse_commandline` function and let the function update the structure based on the arguments.

```
parse_commandline(int argc, char *argv[], items* pItems) {
  pItem->pack_01 = 42;
  ...
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  items items;
  parse_commandline(argc, argv, &items);
  ...
}
```

Comment: This compiles without errors. Is it possible to have the other variables beside "file" initialized from character_y or should i pass them manually from parse_commandline as show in your example? I don't know if this question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a structure to a function in C is no different from passing any other variable.  In your case, you should do it by reference so that you can modify the caller's structure:

```
void parse_commandline(int argc, char *argv[], items *theItems)
```